# $\mathbb E x_t$ and $Cov(x_t,x_s)$ for $(x_t=\cos(\lambda t+ \phi)|t \in \mathbb Z)$, $\lambda \sim U([-\pi,\pi])$

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Consider the stochastic process $(x_t=\cos(\lambda t+ \phi)|t \in \mathbb Z)$

$\phi \in [-\pi,\pi]$ is a real number and $\lambda \sim U([-\pi,\pi])$ a uniformly distributed random variable.

I'm looking for hints how to calculate $\mathbb Ex_t$ and $Cov(x_t,x_s)$.

I thought about using $\cos(a)\cos(b)=1/2(\cos(a+b)+\cos(a-b))$ but I don't know if there are better ways to solve this task.

Comment: Do you know the probability density function of lambda? How can you write an expectation as an integral? Can you write covariance function as an integral?

Comment: @max Yes. I know how to calculate $\mathbb E \lambda$ but I don't know how to do it with $\cos (\lambda t + \phi)$

Comment: For an absolutely continuous random variable X, we have $\mathbb{E}[g(X)]= \int g(x)f(x)dx$ where $f(x)$ is a probability density function of $X$ and the integral is taken over the support of $X$, so in this case from $-\pi$ till $\pi$. Does that help?

Comment: @max Thanks. And for the covariance: how does the common density function look like? And we integrate over $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}$?

Comment: Your process is based on one random variable $\lambda$ for each $t$, so no double integral is needed. But in general, you need to know the joint distribution function between $X_t$ and $X_s$ and integrate it over double integral.